# Asymptote with Ghostscript 10 does not produce pdf or png

Tags: pdf, asymptote, ghostscript

I am running Asymptote version 2.86 on Windows 10. I have installed Ghostscript 10.04 and have a confi.asy file saved in .asy\ directory that specifies the location of Adobe Reader and ImageMagick:

```
import settings;

convert="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI\convert.exe";
pdfviewer="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe";
```

Before updating to the latest Ghostcript version I could run an asy file by typing `asy -f pdf -render 16 filename.asy` and get a pdf output of the code in Adobe Reader. However since updating, Asymptote just produces a window with the output of the code (it seems to be the native renderer since I am able to rotate the 3D graph using the mouse). When I close the window there is nothing saved on the drive.

If I use `-render 0` then I get a pdf output to Adobe reader. Any other setting (>0) fails to produce a pdf file. (By the way for `-render 0` after I close the pdf viewer I get `116.11: runtime: shipout failed`)

Comment: Not sure if these'll help, but I had a similar issue which I was able to solve using these two posts: (1) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700514/asymptote-error-missing-pdf-file-during-compilation (2) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700578/asymptote-code-generates-asy-files-but-asymptote-execution-fails

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am running asymptote using command line to generate pdf or png files which only contain a figure. The issues you encountered have to do with using asymptote as part of a LaTeX document.

Comment: Looking at a past post by @CharlesStaats https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152947/is-it-possible-to-compile-asymptote-asy-file-without-displaying-the-figure he refers to the fact that "the -V option [is] the default when running Asymptote on a single file under MSDOS". The strange thing is that on one Windows 10 computer if I run `asy -f pdf -render 16 test2_contour` I get a pdf file but on another Windows 10 computer with exactly the same GS, Adobe Reader  the same command generates an OpenGL rendering instead of a pdf file.